# Padronizar cor das letras textarea com placeholder

Tags: css, placeholder

A cor do placeholder dos input fica mais forte que a da textarea!

estou usando o CSS assim:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: a cor da textarea fica mais claro do que os inputs...
No Chrome e Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto mais provavelmente será porque estás a aplicar o `font-weight:bold;` no placeholder e na `textarea` não, o que vai fazer com que o texto fique mais forte no **placeholder**.

> O `font-size: 14px;` também poderá contribuir para essa diferença, como acontece neste caso.

Eis um exemplo disto no trecho de código abaixo, o `font-weight:bold;` é apenas aplicado ao placeholder exatamente como no código da tua pergunta. Copia o texto do placeholder e cola na `textarea` para ver o resultado:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Descreva o seu texto aqui..."></textarea>
```

Agora vamos adicionar os mesmos estilos que adicionas-te no **placeholder** para a `textarea`, para que ambos fiquem iguais, ou seja adicionando o `font-weight:bold;` e também o `font-size: 14px;`:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
color: #757575 !important; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;
}

/* font-weight:bold; adicionado à textarea */
textarea { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Descreva o seu texto aqui..."></textarea>
```

Comment: PS: Verifica também se nenhuma cor de estilo está a ser aplicada à `textarea{ }` que seja menos forte que a do `placeholder`

Comment: Mas a cor da textarea ainda continua clarinha! Só fica mais escuro quando tem algum texto dentro dela

Comment: Então pois, pois é assim mesmo que é suposto ser, para que os usuários percebam que é apenas um texto exemplar. Se quiseres que a cor do `placeholder` fique com a mesma cor do texto escrito, basta mudares a cor do texto do placeholder que adicionas-te - `color:#757575;` para - `color:#000;` por exemplo, ou qualquer outra cor que desejares. Tens aqui um [exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/yngu0scf/) no jsFiddle.